# Need to find a unique mathematical expression (not in documentation) that is as short as possible but takes a good amount of time to evaluate

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization, expression-test, expression-construction, example

I am writing a public `ResourceFunction` and I need a good clever use case that should not appear to emulate any examples in the official documentation but will consider examples not commonly used. Definitely no Pause or deliberate time lags. Expression should be as short as possible while take close to 10 seconds to evaluate. I prefer expression NOT be `Table`, `Do`,`For`,`While`, or any other loops or iterators but I shall consider them.

So far I have one expression `expr1` that uses a `Do` with no `Pause` which evaluates on my old laptop in just over 8 seconds.

```
expr1 = Timing[sum = 0; Do[sum += i, {i, 5000000}]; sum]
```

Here are a few examples of what I tried for `expr2` but were too fast and even broke my `Timing` function. `Quit` and `ClearSystemCache[]` did not fix it. There were other things I tried but did not work.

```
(* results in {0.,3.68*10^(30102999)} *)
expr2=Timing[n=2.^1000000000;ScientificForm[n,3]]

(* results in {0.,9.58*10^(301029995663) *)
expr2=Timing[n=2.^1000000000;ScientificForm[n,3]]
```

In short expr2 should be:

1. must use mathematics
2. prefer not in docs (not a hard requirement)
3. short as possible
4. no Pause or other deliberate lags
5. prefer no loops or iterators (not a hard requirement)
6. timing close to 10 seconds

Thank you. I am looking forward to what you guys come up with.

Comment: You indicate that you want an expression that is "mathematical"; however, all of the examples that you give are "numeric".

Comment: @BobHanlon what I meant by mathematical is that they should not be string manipulation, work on files or directories, create web elements, scour the web, system setup or maintenance, etc. in other words the expression should use math directly.

Comment: How about `PadeApproximant[MittagLefflerE[4, x], {x, 1, 6}] // AbsoluteTiming` which results in `{62.3867, large output}`?

Comment: Quite frankly I still don't get what the scope is. I mean the objective that defines what form the analytic function should have. Maybe I am being stupid and it's something well explained, but it's not obvious to me

Comment: @user64494 wow that is badass. i <3 it but unfortunately  its tad bit too long for ResourceFunction use case by 50 seconds . lol do you have anything else in your tool chest?

Comment: `PadeApproximant[MittagLefflerE[4, x], {x, 1, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming` is executed in 6.36297 s.

Comment: Are [MittagLefflerE](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MittagLefflerE.html)
and [PadeApproximantPadeApproximant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PadeApproximant.html) considered to be undocumented?

Comment: how about  `p = Predict[{1} -> {1}, TrainingProgressReporting -> None, 
    TimeGoal -> Quantity[10, "Seconds"]]; // Timing`?

Comment: Of course, these are documented.

Comment: @user64494 thanks. I thought I was going insane. Ok, good. Still don't get what the author wants :-)

Comment: Me too. What a question, such an answer.

Comment: @kcr any equations, math structures , number theory, algebra, trig, calculus, differential equations, statistics, etc. or subjects heavy in math like physics, engineering, economics, etc, so as to differentiate it from other things MMA does like search the web, system tuning, debugging, working with strings, directories, files, control objects, etc.

Comment: @user64494 i like your expression. if you put in an answer ill check as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question, here is a possible one:

```
PadeApproximant[MittagLefflerE[4, x], {x, 1, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> `{6.36297 , large output}`

Comment: (+1). Note worthy: it's much faster to do the `{x,0,5}`

Comment: Sorry for the double comment, but along these lines this is also faster `PadeApproximant[
  HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, x], {x, 0, 
   5}] // AbsoluteTiming` yields `{0.01508,stuff...}`. And of course, the much humbler `Series[HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1}, {3, 3, 3}, x], {x, 0, 
   5}] // AbsoluteTiming` gives `{0.014726,stuff}`

Comment: @kcr  can you modify `Series[..]//AbsoluteTiming` so that it goes for about 5 seconds?

Comment: @user64494 thank you answer was accepted. here is how i shall use it. i dont want to reveal my `ResourceFunction` yet so `Beep` will stand in for it: `Timing[(beeg = 
   Iconize[PadeApproximant[MittagLefflerE[4, x], {x, 1, 5}], 
    "beeg output"]; Beep[]; beeg)]`.

Comment: @JulesManson you can play a bit with it, sure. I guess for higher order in the expansion you will get the desired timeframe